# Join tables with prioritization of value

Tags: mysql

So i have 2 tables with the following schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `languages` (
  `code` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL, // language code
  `name` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL, // native language name
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `langs_local` (
  `code` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL, // original language code
  `code_local` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL, // local language code
  `name` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL, // localized name
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`,`code_local`),
  KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `code_local` (`code_local`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

The idea is that table `languages` holds language code and language name in it'snative form, while table `langs_local`holds the localized language names added as needed. So if i need a list of languages in it's native form (for frontend) i go to `languages` but if i need a localized list (for BackOffice) i use `langs_local`.

I'm having problem with getting the localized language names. Imagine the backend language is set to `pt-PT` (Portuguese (Portugal)), with a fallback language of `en` (regionless English).

For each language i need to get the `pt-PT` version (if it exists), otherwise the `pt` version (if it exists), otherwise the `en`version (which does exist for sure).

I can't just do a 'SELECT * FROM langs_local WHERE code_local = 'pt-PT'`and if empty get the next possibility and so on because there could be partial content with`pt-PT` that should be kept and only the others should be got with following fallbacks.

Table `languages` defines what language codes exist in total (or the `en` localized could do that too).

Is there a way to do this in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - i think i found a convoluted way to do this

```
SELECT `languages`.`code`, `languages`.`name` AS `nativeName`, `local`.`name` AS `localizedName`
FROM `languages`
INNER JOIN (SELECT `langs_local`.`code`, `langs_local`.`code_local`, `langs_local`.`name`, `l`.`priority` 
                FROM `langs_local` 
                INNER JOIN (SELECT `tmp`.`code`, `tmp`.`code_local`, `tmp`.`priority` 
                                FROM (SELECT `code`, `code_local`, (CASE WHEN `code_local` = 'pt-PT' THEN 1 WHEN `code_local` = 'pt' THEN 2 WHEN `code_local` = 'en' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END) AS `priority` 
                                    FROM `langs_local`) AS `tmp` 
                                WHERE `tmp`.`priority` = (SELECT  MIN(CASE WHEN `tmp2`.`code_local` = 'pt-PT' THEN 1 WHEN `tmp2`.`code_local` = 'pt' THEN 2 WHEN `tmp2`.`code_local` = 'en' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END) AS `priority` 
                                                        FROM `langs_local` AS `tmp2`
                                                        WHERE `tmp2`.`code` = `tmp`.`code`)) AS `l` 
                    ON `langs_local`.`code` = `l`.`code` AND `langs_local`.`code_local` = `l`.`code_local`) AS `local` 
    ON `languages`.`code` = `local`.`code`
```

Any comments or simplifications are welcome though.